# How to formulate NOT in the extended boolean model

Tags: model, boolean

I think this is simple SET theory but I do not know how to create the formula when it contains a "NOT".
Formula:
AND AND example:[and and example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81mLZ.png)

Here is an OR AND combination - you can see that the OR term has been replaced by the AND formula. I just can't understand how this would be formulate if "OR AND" was "OR BUT NOT" (i.e. OR AND NOT) instead??
[red = AND part; yellow = OR first term](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd8PY.jpg)

I would like to know how to formulate please:

1) x AND y AND NOT Z

2) x OR y AND NOT z OR w

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it - managed to formulate it myself